# Angular binding breaks in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to bind input field values to members of a list. I use ngFor to makes input fields for each member. The problem is that when I push new member to the list, all the input fields on template become empty. The two-way binding still exists because when I change the field value, the member value in list also changes. All I need is a way to keep the member values in template input fields when I push new member to the list. 
Here is my html code:

```
<form action="submit">
  <div *ngFor="let member of MyList; let i = index">
    <label for="name"> Name:
      <input type="text" name='name'  [(ngModel)] ='MyList[i].name'></label>
  </div>
</form>
<button (click)="addMember()">add parameter</button>
```

AddMember function just pushes a new member to the end of the list so the template also changes and adds new field. Everything is find at the beginning but as soon as I push a new member to the list all the previous fields become empty, although the name value of those members is not blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a form, each `name` has to be unique to be evaluated as separate form fields. You can use the index for this:

```
<input type="text" name='name{{i}}'  [(ngModel)] ='MyList[i].name'></label>
```

Unless you do this, whenever you push a new empty field, all fields will become empty as they are evaluated as the same field. This happens despite that you use `ngModel`.

Comment: Yeah, I remembered when I struggled with the same issue. Sometimes the solution is so simple that it's annoying :D